# HAProxy path /splunk to splunk (/en-US/account/login?return_to=%2Fen-US%2F)

Tags: haproxy

I'd like to forward requests from server/splunk to a running splunk application at server:8000. Without haproxy, if I visit splunk directly on port 8000 I get the following rewritten destination:

server:8000/en-US/account/login?return_to=%2Fen-US%2F

Here I'm able to login and everything works as expected. However, with the following haproxy configuration I wind up with the following destination, which is a 404:

server/en-US

What's really confusing is this 404 is reported by the following http server, *not* splunk. This is the default_backend Apache server listening on 5001, as shown in the config.

```
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at theserver.example.com Port 80
```

Here is my configuration:

```
frontend  main 192.168.1.5:80

    acl url_static  path_beg /splunk
    use_backend static  if url_static
    default_backend             app

backend static
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)splunk[/]?(.*)     \1\2
    server  static 192.168.1.5:8000 check


backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
```

Comment: Your configuration is sending everything to the http server that doesn't start with /splunk.  server/en-US does not match that so it's going to the http server.  What's confusing?

Comment: Read your headers and there should be no real mystery, here... Consider what `server:8000/en-US/account/login?return_to=%2Fen-US%2F` is telling you.  Splunk, on login, is going to redirect to ("return_to=") `/en-US/`, almost certainly via a `30X` HTTP redirect... which means you need HAProxy to rewrite the `Location:` header to prepend `/splunk` to the path the browser will be instructed to try to use... or configure splunk to accept and expect `/splunk` if possible, so you don't have to strip it off and add it back.

Comment: I follow to some extent but do you have haproxy configuration syntax I could see?